# JS node styles don't get applied if in a if block

Tags: javascript, css

Neither style top nor bottom is applied. How can I fix this?

```js
let btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.textContent = "Button";
btn.style.position = "fixed";
if (this.anchorBottom) {
    btn.style.bottom = this.y;
    console.log(true)
}
else {
    btn.style.top = this.y;
}
btn.style.right = 0;
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: I'm assuming you need to provide a unit for the values. Try `btn.style.bottom = \`${this.y}px\``?

Comment: @Quentin good spot for the duplicate.

Comment: @evolutionxbox — That was epascarello. It's probably right, but I wasn't sure so just hit the needs debugging option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide a unit as well.

```
let btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.style.position = "fixed";
if (this.anchorBottom) {
  btn.style.bottom = `${this.y}px`;
  console.log(true)
} else {
  btn.style.top = `${this.y}px`;
}
btn.style.right = '0px';
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

Remember, [you're not limited to only using `px` values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Values_and_Units).